# Reading a file with variable line lengths c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program that reads a file line by line.
However the lines has variable lengths.

Here is the flow of the program:

1. First, I will prompt the user to enter the number of line they want to view
2. Basing to input from the user, I will output that line.

I am thinking two ways to implement this:

1. I will use getline() plus a counter, once it get to the line, then read it
2. I will use seekg to jump to the position right away and read it using getline.(not sure about this since seekg seeks by position);

   I believe seekg is ideal to use, since it faster than reading line by line (if possible I want to use seekg) . 
   However, the lines have different lengths and Im not sure if is possible to seek the lines easily.

   Was wondering of someone could give me a suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: If the lines are of variable length, you *can't* use any seeking method, because it's impossible to know the position beforehand. You unfortunately have to go with the first version (`std::getline` and counter), if you want a simple solution.

Comment: Isn't it better to read the whole file when you're going to do that anyway? You can then create an index of line beginnings. Or if the file is too large to be kept in memory, you could create the index first and then use it for seeking. Disk files are of binary nature and lines are just bytes betweeen special sequences delimiting them.

Comment: You have come up with quite the impossible problem to solve. It's almost like asking: *"How can I get the length of a string without counting the characters? I don't want to count characters, because I think not counting characters is faster than counting characters."*

Comment: thanks for your quick responses, yah I was just thinking if I can use seekg .. unfortunately its not.

Comment: It's likely not significant performance/memory wise, but conceptually calling `.ignore(..., '\n')` is elegant for being indicative of the disinterest in the lines before the one you really want to `getline`, though countering that using it probably complicates the code a little....

Answer (score 0):

Use get line function , it reads complete line (till new line char '\n')

```
#include< fstream>
#include< string>
using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    string line;
    ifstream infile("infile.txt");
    while (getline(infile,line))
    {
        //Process each line data here
    }
}
```